# Best way to parallelize this for loop with multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I currently have a code block like this

```
UINT8* u = getResult();
for (UINT64 counter = 0; counter < MaxCount; counter++)
{
    for (UINT64 index = 0; index < c_uOneMB; ++index)
    {
        *u++ = genValue();
    }
}
```

Now in order to make this run faster. I am doing something like this. Basically splitting the inner thread into a method. However I have two concerns which I am not sure how to tackle.

1. *u++ how do I handle that?
2. Before calling doSomethingElse() all the threads need to .join()

Any suggestions on how to accomplish that?

```
void doSomething(UINT8* u)
{
      for (UINT64 index = 0; index < c_uOneMB; ++index)
      {
          *u++ = genValue();
      }
}

UINT8* u = getResult();
for (UINT64 counter = 0; counter < MaxCount; counter++)
{
    std::thread t(doSomething,u);
}

doSomethingElse();
```

Comment: Would love to know why close is voted ?

Comment: why two `for` loops in first example? Why not one loop which iterates `MaxCount * c_uOneMB` times? Second example is not equivalent to first one, one thread overrides results of other one.

Comment: @MarekR that makes sense. In that case how do I make it faster.

Comment: 1. profile code 2. Reduce time complexity of code which was found to be slow. 3. use threads as last resort. We can't help since you didn't provide significant details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With little details you have provided I can give only this:

```cpp
std::generate_n(std::execution::par, getResult(), MaxCount * c_uOneMB, genValue);
```

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag

Comment: Note that this assume that the parallel STL is supported, which is not the case for all compilers. Clang for example does not support it yet unfortunately.

Comment: @JérômeRichard it was tagged C++17 so using a headline C++17 feature is valid

Answer (score 2):

> Best way to parallize this for loop with multiple threads

*Best* way depends on many factors and is subjective. In fact, sometimes (perhaps most of the time) non-parallelised code is faster. If speed is most important, then the best way is whatever you have measured to be fastest.

Using the standard library algorithms is usually straightforward:

```
std::generate_n(
    std::execution::par_unseq,
    u,
    MaxCount * c_uOneMB,
    genValue);
```

Comment: Same comment as in the other answer: this assume that the parallel STL is supported (Clang does not yet).